# What should I do with my question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

My question is here: [I can't get Cinnamon to stop freezing, how can I revert it back?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76516/i-cant-get-cinnamon-to-stop-freezing-how-can-i-revert-it-back)

I ended up doing something wrong and Cinnamon is now in limbo, as in, it doesn't even recognize what version it is and it won't purge / remove.

The answer I received can be useful to someone else, but at the same time, I'm worried that it might make things worse for someone else at the same time. (Long story short, Cinnamon didn't want to downgrade but it ended up removing files that 1.8 needed before realizing that 'hey, won't'; when I tried to reinstall 1.8, when I realized it wouldn't downgrade, it wouldn't reinstall. `cinnamon --version` ended up giving me some garbled response pretty much saying can't do something with cinnamon. )

Since there is an answer, I can't delete this question myself anymore, even if I wanted to. I don't know what should happen with this question, either should we leave it up or should it be deleted? (I'm okay with either one. I just know that it no longer helps me :-/ )

Answer (score 6):

As long as the answer might be helpful to someone else you should leave the question. You've already got a comment saying it might be dangerous, so other people should be forewarned if they want to try

Comment: Okay, just making sure. Thank you!